# Comma after variable assignment in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, for-loop, variable-assignment

```
function ReplaceContentInContainer(matchClass,content)
    {
    var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('*'), i;
    for (i in elems)
        {
        if((" "+elems[i].className+" ").indexOf(" "+matchClass+" ") > -1)
            {
            elems[i].innerHTML = content;
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to figure out what the comma does in the variable assignment `('*'), i;`
and what that means in the `for (i in e)` loop.

My best guess is that `e` is assigned to both all the elements in the document node as well as  `i`. So does that mean that `i` is a count or reference of the number of elements in the array `e` (is it an array?)?

edit:
Okay. It's just instantiating the variable (`i`) and then `i`, in the `for` loop, counts all the elements in the object `elem`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That simply separate the declarations.

```
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('*'), i;
```

is the same as

```
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
var i;
```

One is more concise, the other one might be seen as more readable.

In your precise case, you could have used

```
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
for (var i in elems)
```

which would be, in my opinion, the best as the purpose of `i` would have been obvious.

As the scope of a variable is the function (or global) and not the block, it would have been exactly identical.

Answer (score 2):

That comma is because you define the variable `i` in the local scope, it's simply part of the `var` statement. If there wasn't a comma `i` would be a global.

Your statement is the same as:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
var i;
```

If you use tool for static analysis of the quality of your code, like JSLint for example, it'll force you to write:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('*'),
    i;
```

In few reasons:

1. You define both variables (so you don't have globals)
2. You don't have extra `var` (you write less... :-))
3. Your code is more readable than the one line version
4. You define all your variables at the same place which is easier for reading than:

   for (var i in elems) {
       //do something
   }

There's similar concept in perl, for example:

```
my ($var1, $var2);
```

In JavaScript it's the same but you don't need to put the variables inside a list.

Answer (score 1):

`i` is the part of the `var` statement.. so it is just creating a new variable...
you code is same as

```
var elements=document.getElementsByTagName('*');
var i;
```